# Javascript API/Rails best practice passing data from javascript to controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using a Javascript API (Facebook) and need to pass data to/from my controller with and without a form submit. What is the best practice approach to this? I'd assume it's common enough so I hope what I'm reading about creating a Web Service for Ajax to get the data to the server is misguided.

Comment: you can fake a form via ajax using FormData(), which might help you re-use the same backend for both front-end methods.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis. FormData looks like a nice clean approach but I'd still like to avoid Ajax is there's a Rails platform solution. Maybe there's not one?